# Mongoid nested set helper same as in awesome_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, acts-as-nested-set

Gem [Awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) has useful helper(nested_set_options) which provides buiding tree for select elements.

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" } %>
```

Gem [Mongoid_nested_set](https://github.com/thinkwell/mongoid_nested_set) is a mongo port of awesome_nested_set. But it hasn't such helper.
How can I solve this?